# Strange behaviour on !Clipboard command : IMACROS

Tags: macros, keyboard, clipboard, imacros, clip

I am using a Imacros for fill in the form. In the form I have to click a `Browse` button and give a full path. I take a full path with another script and with using `clip` command(Batch) I copy to clipboard.

Now, the problem is : When I use `!clipboard` command on `textfield` or `textarea` I can get the correct path. But when i use at `browse` it is automatically added `-` at the end of the path.

this my line which try to copy to browse :

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=NAME:frm_edit_container_doku ATTR=NAME:FILE CONTENT={{!CLIPBOARD}}
```

The result :

```
`xxx_to_yyy_2013_11_26T12-40-45.zip -`
```

It should finish with `.zip`. Where does this `-` come from ? 
I will be crazy on this issue.

Comment: probably it is added when you scrape data and insert it in clipboard

Comment: @Bestmacros but when i use `{{!CLIPBOARD}}` in `textfield`  it doesn't add anything, but when click the `browse button` and use `{{!CLIPBOARD}}` in it. The problem occurs.

Comment: without page code it is impossible to understand where is the problem